# i want to wait php function(from another call) while it processing

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, prepared-statement

[language : php]

i have a function that have three mysql prepare statements..
when call the function from Api while the function is already processing .. i want to wait that call and resume after the processing finish ...

actually my problem is ... in my function
my first mysql prepare statement select a value from database and bind that result..
the second prepare statement use that result ..

but another call select value from database without wait for the second prepare statement execute from first call...

```
//function sample...

public function saveSales($query1,$query2,$query3){

//query1 execute and return a result from database
//using that result execute query 2
//execute query 3

// i want to run this three querys without interrupt from another call
}
```

My Actual Code :

[index.php : slimframework(Api)]

```
$app->post('/savesalesnew', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $request_data = $request->getParsedBody(); 
    $sm= $request_data['sm'];
    $st= $request_data['st'];
    $trans = $request_data['trans'];
    $user= $request_data['user'];
    $pass = $request_data['pass'];
    $maxfind = $request_data['maxfind'];

    $db = new DbOperations; 
    $queryPostResult = $db->saveSales($sm,$st,$trans,$user,$pass,$maxfind);
    $response_data=$queryPostResult; 
    $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(200);    


});
```

[Db operations.php]

```
public function saveSales($sm,$st,$trans,$user,$pass,$maxfind){    


    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT emp_pass FROM emp WHERE emp_name ='$user'");
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($password); 
                    $stmt->fetch();           

    if(strcmp($pass, $password) !== 0)  {
        return false;
    }     

    $stmt->close();



 $mysqli = new mysqli(//connection parameters);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);


 $stmt1 = $this->con->prepare("$maxfind");
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($maxInvoice); 
                    $stmt1->fetch();
    $stmt1->close();


    $sm = str_replace("#%#@#@#23@#@3", $maxInvoice, $sm);
    $st = str_replace("#%#@#@#23@#@3", $maxInvoice, $st);
    $trans = str_replace("#%#@#@#23@#@3", $maxInvoice, $trans);
$mysqli->query("$sm");
$mysqli->query("$st");
$mysqli->query("$trans");

$mysqli->commit();

$mysqli->close();


return true;


}
//-----------------------------
```

Comment: all php functions are blocking (nothing happens until they finish)  by default, so I can't see how what you describe is possible, need to see the actual code used.

Comment: thats right @tim

Comment: @tim  i added actual code to question , please check..

Answer (score 0):

if you have long process on server, you need a column flag in database if data ready or not. set "0" if data not ready "1" in progress "2" ready.